# Can not convert json to Model

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have json from url. I need Convert This json to Model

```
{
    "someField": 3,
    "datesField": ["2017-08-19",
    "2017-08-20",
    "2017-08-26",
    "2018-12-30"]
}
```

I create models for mapping

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
private class Response{
    @JsonProperty("someField")
    private int someField;
    @JsonProperty("datesField")
    private DatesField datesField;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
private class DatesField{
    private String[] strings;
}
```

try convert

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Dates dates = mapper.readValue(forObject, Response.class);
```

I get error when try convert:

> Can not deserialize instance of packeg.DatesField out of START_ARRAY
>   token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json attributed is incorrect according to the model. There is no array of `datesField` type but an array of strings within the `datesField` object.

Your object json equivalent shall be:

```
{
    "someField": 3,
    "datesField": {
        "strings":["2017-08-19",
         "2017-08-20",
         "2017-08-26",
         "2018-12-30"]
     }
}
```

---

Or the other way, if you need to adapt to the json response, change your model as suggested by @xenteros to:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
private class Response{
    @JsonProperty("someField")
    private int someField;
    @JsonProperty("datesField")
    private String[] datesField;
}
```

---

Also, note that the java code to map the response should be changed from:

```
Dates dates = mapper.readValue(forObject, Response.class);
```

to

```
Response response = mapper.readValue(forObject, Response.class);
```

Comment: How can I mapping this text? API return me this text and I need mapping it to Model

Comment: @user5620472 Updated the answer with both the approaches. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "someField": 3,
    "datesField": ["2017-08-19",
    "2017-08-20",
    "2017-08-26",
    "2018-12-30"]
}
```

is equivalent to

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
private class Response{
    @JsonProperty("someField")
    private int someField;
    @JsonProperty("datesField")
    private String[] datesField;
}
```

You should rather parse the following `json`:

```
{
    "someField": 3,
    "datesField": {
         "strings":
            ["2017-08-19",
            "2017-08-20",
            "2017-08-26",
            "2018-12-30"]
        }
}
```