# how to convert this Response into Model

Tags: java, android, json

I have query about converting Model from response.

```
{
   "data":{
      "dataList":[
         {
            "itemCode":"item-49861",
            "itemTypeKey":"drugs",
            "itemCategoryKey":"general",
            "itemSubCategoryKey":"fever and pain",
            "itemName":"Combiflam",
            "displayName":"Combiflam tablet 250mg"
         },
         {
            "itemCode":"item-298611",
            "itemTypeKey":"drugs",
            "itemCategoryKey":"general",
            "itemSubCategoryKey":"fever and pain",
            "itemName":"Crocin",
            "displayName":"Crocin tablet 250mg"
         }
      ],
      "pageSize":2,
      "dataSize":2
   }
}
```

Comment: Not a valid `JSON` you can check it here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not convert json to Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759727/can-not-convert-json-to-model)

Comment: You can use [`jsonschema2pojo`](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to convert your response in to model class

Comment: @MahavirJain question about how to convert.

Comment: here is the valid json  you had 2 extra double quotes   `{
    "data": {"dataList":[{"itemCode":"item-49861","itemTypeKey":"drugs","itemCategoryKey":"general","itemSubCategoryKey":"fever and pain","itemName":"Combiflam","displayName":"Combiflam tablet 250mg"},{"itemCode":"item-298611","itemTypeKey":"drugs","itemCategoryKey":"general","itemSubCategoryKey":"fever and pain","itemName":"Crocin","displayName":"Crocin tablet 250mg"}],"pageSize":2,"dataSize":2}
}`

Comment: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/   Best online tool to convert JSON to Java POJO class

Comment: @ManoharReddy that's why i am asking about this, because i have received response that i mentioned in question.

Comment: Its not a valid json , ask your server team to send valid json response , It's not your problem . You should not be using this response even if you can parse it some how .

Answer (score 0):

Android studio  File->Settings..->Plugins-->Browse repositores.. seach "GsonFormat"
copy data in

Answer (score 0):

Here Are Model Classes of Your Response.
Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ For Convert Json Response to Model.

```
public class Data {

@SerializedName("dataList")
@Expose
private List<DataList> dataList = null;
@SerializedName("pageSize")
@Expose
private Integer pageSize;
@SerializedName("dataSize")
@Expose
private Integer dataSize;

public List<DataList> getDataList() {
return dataList;
}

public void setDataList(List<DataList> dataList) {
this.dataList = dataList;
}

public Integer getPageSize() {
return pageSize;
}

public void setPageSize(Integer pageSize) {
this.pageSize = pageSize;
}

public Integer getDataSize() {
return dataSize;
}

public void setDataSize(Integer dataSize) {
this.dataSize = dataSize;
}

}
```

---

```
public class DataList {

@SerializedName("itemCode")
@Expose
private String itemCode;
@SerializedName("itemTypeKey")
@Expose
private String itemTypeKey;
@SerializedName("itemCategoryKey")
@Expose
private String itemCategoryKey;
@SerializedName("itemSubCategoryKey")
@Expose
private String itemSubCategoryKey;
@SerializedName("itemName")
@Expose
private String itemName;
@SerializedName("displayName")
@Expose
private String displayName;

public String getItemCode() {
return itemCode;
}

public void setItemCode(String itemCode) {
this.itemCode = itemCode;
}

public String getItemTypeKey() {
return itemTypeKey;
}

public void setItemTypeKey(String itemTypeKey) {
this.itemTypeKey = itemTypeKey;
}

public String getItemCategoryKey() {
return itemCategoryKey;
}

public void setItemCategoryKey(String itemCategoryKey) {
this.itemCategoryKey = itemCategoryKey;
}

public String getItemSubCategoryKey() {
return itemSubCategoryKey;
}

public void setItemSubCategoryKey(String itemSubCategoryKey) {
this.itemSubCategoryKey = itemSubCategoryKey;
}

public String getItemName() {
return itemName;
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
this.itemName = itemName;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
return displayName;
}

public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
this.displayName = displayName;
}

}
```

---

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;

public Data getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```